# Code compliance of using UHMW (Ultra High Molecular Weight Polyethylene) shims for deck leveling

Tags: wood, code-compliance, deck, shim

I'm building a deck that will partially sit on an existing concrete slab. Slab is slated and I need to level the joists with shims. I'm planning to use custom cut UHMW (Ultra High Molecular Weight Polyethylene) pieces as shims, as they're much more durable than wood. But I'm not sure if they would give me a headache later when I try to sell the house; i.e., if an inspector sees them, would he/she/they raise it as an issue?

I live in Beaverton, Oregon. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How much shimming will be required?

Comment: @JACK, on one end it will be 1 inch thick, and on the other it will be 2.5 inches thick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t think there will be any issues using UHMW. It will never rot and it can be drilled and screwed it wont break under impact so I only see advantages it is a vapor / moisture barrier also. I have used it for pool projects but not often because of cost, I live just south Benton , lane and Lynn counties and they would not have a problem with UHMW.

Comment: I've seen a lot of that done down here in Florida, works great and inspectors like it+1